# Set Background color of GridView Row during page postback

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid with few rows. On satisying a certain condition, I need to change the background color of the row that satifies that condition. I do this in the rowdatabound event of the grid, but then it loses the color during the page postback. How do I fix this issue?
My code is like so.

```
If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
    Dim lblShowBreak As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label = e.row.FindControl("lblShowBreak")
    Dim lblIsBreak As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label = e.row.FindControl("lblIsBreak")

    If Trim(lblIsBreak.Text) = "Y" Then
       e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Why you need a for each inside rowdatabound event since it's iterating rows...

Comment: Yeah I don't need that For loop, please check my edited code.

Comment: Please debug and check whether the value of `lblIsBreak` is `"Y"` after postback.

Comment: @Aishvarya you are getting the value of `lblShowBreak` label but in if condition you are using `lblIsBreak`, plz also mentioned that how you find the value of `lblIsBreak` label. thanks

Comment: @Rahul pl check my updated code.

Comment: you are missing `e` in the code while finding the value of `lblIsBreak `....i think this is the problem.

Comment: plz check that `lblIsBreak` is getting the value or not.use debugger.

Comment: @Rahul, I get the value. But I don't get the color because the page is posted back.

Comment: show me your `Load` event code of the page.

Comment: The thing is I load the grid on the SelectedIndexChanged event of my dropdowns.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29886/discussion-between-aishvarya-and-rahul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this..my fix is as follows.

```
If Trim(lblIsBreak.Text) = "Y" Then
   lblShowBreak.Visible = True
   For i = 0 To gvTimeTable.Columns.Count - 1
       e.Row.Cells(i).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray
   Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can mark e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black in the OnPreRender method every time. In this case state will be saved always.

Comment: I think, you should check view state value of the Grid control and the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `RowDataBound` event of `Grid View` like

```
Protected Sub GridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView.RowDataBound
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
     If `set your condition here` Then
     e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
End If
     End If
End Sub
```

You have to use something like that.

Hope You understand and works for you.

Comment: you are getting the value of `lblShowBreak` label but in if condition you are using `lblIsBreak`, plz also mentioned that how you find the value of `lblIsBreak` label.